Установить FFMPEG 7.1 на Ubuntu
Новеньки в самостоятельной настройке vps.
В интернете полно статей о том как установить ffmpeg. Но в каждой из них не последняя версия...
Хотел бы установить именно последнюю версию 7.1, которая вышла если не ошибаюсь в сентябре этого года.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какова последовательность и какие именно команды необходимо выполнить консоле. Чтобы на выходе получить установленную ffmpeg версию 7.1?
OC.Ubuntu версия 20.04

Соберите из исходников: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Если что-то не выходит, пробуйте в docker

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg

Спс, скачал архив от сюда https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:7.1-3ubuntu1

Тот что 10мб, далее залил на сервер пока разместил в произвольной папке. Но какие необходимо предпринять дальнейшие шаги? Как установит, чтобы из консоли возможно было выполнять команды?
